# Efficiently looping through lists in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator

I need to make a python function which, given ordered list `a` and `b` returns `True` if there exists an item in a for which holds that there is an item in `b` that is `a+1`.

This is of course easily done by using something like this:

```
for item in a:
  if (a+1 in b):
     return True
```

However, I need to make this as efficient as possible because the function will be used to process loads of data. The tip that was given me was to use the `iter()` and `next()` operations, but I have not found a way to use these for effecient processing yet. Does anyone know how to implement these, or use another fast algorythm?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could convert `b` to a set, or you could order it to find stuff in it more quickly. I don't know why you're being told to use `iter` and `next`.

Comment: Do you mean `for item in a: if item+1 in b: return True`? If `b` is large, make it a set rather than a list.

Comment: The list was specifically ordered, and I am supposed to use this fact to gain speed.

Comment: if it is possible, convert `a` to generator function. This will make your code more memory efficient. Just looping through the list in generator will not help though. Use case here is if you fetch data from somewhere or generate it somehow https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: @wim nonconstructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for your answers! I ended up using a combined version of your solutions:

```
a = iter(l1)
b = iter(l2)
i = next(a)
j = next(b)
try:
    while (i):
        if i + 1 == j:
            return True
        elif i + 1 > j:
            j = next(b)
        else:
            i = next(a)
except StopIteration:
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two options that are more efficient.

1. Go through each element in `a`, and perform a binary search for `element+1` in `b`.

Time complexity: O(n*log(m)) where n = `|a|` and m = `|b|`.

```
    for element in a:
        if binary_search(a, element+1):
            return True
    return False
```

2. Increment two counters through [0,`|a|`) and [0,`|b|`), say `i` and `j`.  Loop while `i` is less than `|a|` and `j` is less than `|b|`.  Compare `a[i] + 1` with `b[j]`.  If they are equal, return `True`.  If the value of `a[i] + 1 > b[j]`, increment `j`.  Otherwise, increment `i`.

Time complexity: O(n+m) where n = `|a|` and m = `|b|`.

```
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        if a[i] + 1 == b[j]:
            return True
        elif a[i] + 1 > b[j]:
            j += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return False
```

Comment: I think we have the same algorithm, but quite a different implementation in our answers. IMHO the condition in the while loop is incomplete: `... and j < len(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: not very well tested code. Assuming sorted lists as you wrote.

The idea behind the hint with `iter` and `next` is that within a single loop you can advance in one or in the other list. If the first number is too small, you try the next first number. If the second one is too small, you try the text second number.

```
def test1(a, b): 
    ia = iter(a)
    ib = iter(b)
    try:
        ea = next(ia)
        eb = next(ib)
        while True:
            print("debug: comparing {} -- {}".format(ea, eb))
            diff = ea - eb
            if diff == -1: 
                print("debug: OK!")
                return True
            elif diff < -1: 
                ea = next(ia)
            else:
                eb = next(ib)
    except StopIteration:
        print("debug: not found")
        return False

lista=[1,2,4,10,31,33,45,67]
listb=[7,16,22,29,34,39,49,59,60,100,200,300]
test1(lista, listb)
```

The the output shows the algorithm at work:

```
debug: comparing 1 -- 7
debug: comparing 2 -- 7
debug: comparing 4 -- 7
debug: comparing 10 -- 7
debug: comparing 10 -- 16
debug: comparing 31 -- 16
debug: comparing 31 -- 22
debug: comparing 31 -- 29
debug: comparing 31 -- 34
debug: comparing 33 -- 34
debug: OK!
```